# Need assistance regarding asset library

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary

I am using this code to retrieve all images form my device but its not returning an result

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    void (^assetEnumerator)(ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
        if(result != NULL) {
            NSLog(@"See Asset: %@", result);
            [_assets addObject:result];
            // Here storing the asset's image URL's in NSMutable array urlStoreArr
            NSURL *url = [[result defaultRepresentation] url];
            [_urlStoreArr addObject:url];
        }
    };

    void (^assetGroupEnumerator)(ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) =  ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
    {
        if(group != nil)
        {
            [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
        }
    };

    _urlStoreArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _assets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    [_library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAlbum
                           usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
                         failureBlock: ^(NSError *error) {
                             NSLog(@"Failure");
                         }];



    [self UploadImagesToServer];

}

-(void) UploadImagesToServer
{
    for (int i=0; i<[_urlStoreArr count]; i++)
    {
        // To get the each image URL here...

        NSString *str = [_urlStoreArr objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"str: %@",str);

        // Need to upload the images to my server..
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is a nice tutorial using Assets library may be helpful for you.  http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/08/asset-libraries-and-blocks-in-ios-4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `_urlStoreArr` before it is initialized.

When you are defining blocks, they take the current local value of variables that you use in the block.

So, in the `assetEnumerator` block you are using `_urlStoreArr` but you aren't initialising it until later in the code.

I'm assuming that `_urlStoreArr` is an iVar, since it has a leading underscore. If you are using ARC, then the iVar is initialised to `nil`, so your `assetEnumerator` block is sending a message to `nil`. This is legal in Objective-C, but it just returns `nil`.

You have two options to fix this.

1. Move the declaration of `_urlStoreArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` above the definition of the `assetEnumerator` block
2. The preferred way - don't use the iVar directly, use property syntax. i.e. rather than `[_urlStoreArr addObject:url];` try `[self.urlStoreArr addObject:url];`. This works because when using property access, you aren't using the current value of `_urlStoreArr` at the time of definition, you are using the value at the time the block runs, which is after the iVar has been initialised.

Comment: thanks for reply, but when viewdidload will execute the blocks are not going to call, so this way _urlStoreArr will alloc init first...

Comment: It's not about when the blocks run, but when they are defined. You are using the iVar directly, the block is storing that reference as at the  time of creation. It doesn't matter that the block has not run.